# Escaping quotes from Rails Variables when using them for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, escaping, quotes

I am having problems when trying to use a rails variable within javascript code.

For example, I might define a link_to_remote, with parameter
`:complete => "alert('my_var');"`

If `my_var = "I'm testing."`, then the javascript code will break due to the single quote closing the code prematurely. If I try using `escape_javascript(my_var)` so that the quote gets turned into `\'`, it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

I've noticed that when you try `alert('I\'m testing');` there's a problem, but if you do `alert('I\\'m testing')`, it works. Since escape_javascript only turns `'` into `\'`, rather than `\\'`, does somebody have a suggestion for how to handle this?

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> when you try `alert('I\'m testing');` there's a problem

Backslash is also an escape in Ruby strings! So the string literal:

```
"alert('I\'m testing');"
```

means the string:

```
alert('I'm testing');
```

the backslash is gone already before JavaScript gets a look at it. When you are writing a JavaScript string literal *inside* a Ruby string literal you need to escape the escape, `\\`, to get a real `\` that will then, in JavaScript, escape the apostrophe.

`escape_javascript` correctly generates the backslash for JavaScript, if a backslash was included in its input. But again, if you're writing a string literal, you have to escape the backslash to get a real backslash:

```
escape_javascript("\b")     -> this is a backspace character!
escape_javascript("\\b")    -> this is backslash-then-letter-b;
                               escaped for JavaScript literal to double-backslash-then-b.
```

So, this is fine:

```
"'"+escape_javascript(myvar)+"'"
```

alternatively, you can use a JSON encoder to create the JavaScript string literal including the surrounding quotes.

Comment: it has also a simple "j" alias: "'"+j(myvar)+"'"

Comment: A note for recent readers: as of rails 3.2 (and perhaps before) the method is `escape_javascript` and not `javascript_escape`