# What is wrong with following javascript string/ escaping quotes in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I am using calendar helper

```
cell.innerHTML = '<%= calendar_for('start_date')%>';
```

The html generated by the tag is giving syntax error.

```
cell.innerHTML = '<img alt="Calendar" 
                       class="calendar-trigger" 
                       id="start_date_trigger"     
                       src="/application/images/calendar.png?13282" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    Calendar.setup({inputField : 'start_date', 
                    ifFormat : '%Y-%m-%d', 
                    button :'start_date_trigger' });
</script>';
```

What can be the quick solution for such problems?

How can I escape quotes using Rails?

Comment: Could you post the exact error please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171182/escaping-quotes-from-rails-variables-when-using-them-for-javascript

Comment: I am getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL' near closing of <img/> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the escape_javascript helper

```
cell.innerHTML = '<%= escape_javascript(calendar_for('start_date')) %>';
```

Comment: @mashit: you can use alias of `escape_javascript` like `cell.innerHTML = '<%= j calendar_for('start_date')%>';`

Comment: thnx, shingara and @Hardik. this was useful. also can any one of you help me with these questions.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289486/redmine-plugin-requires-restart-after-every-code-change  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017651/ide-for-redmine-rails-and-configuring-the-project  It would be appreciated if you can provide some directions.